# Creating an even and odd array of specific parameters from an original array

Tags: java, bluej

Write a program to accept 15 random numbers into a 1D array. Sort the array using Bubble Sort. After sorting, transfer and store all the even numbers and odd numbers into separate arrays. Display the unsorted original array and the sorted even and odd arrays with appropriate messages

I have been trying to to create the even and odd arrays but its giving null values while printing

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Assignment10
{
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arr[] = new int[15];
        
        System.out.println("Enter 15 numbers");
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)//intializing the main array
        {
            arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        int temp;
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<arr.length-1; j++)
            {
                if(arr[j] > arr[j+1])
                {
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1] = temp;
                }

            }
        }
        int counter = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
        {
            
                if(arr[i]%2 == 0)
                {
                    counter ++;
                }
        }
        
         int[] even = new int[15];
        int[] odd = new int[15];
        int evenCount = 0, oddCount = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
                even[evenCount++] = arr[i];
            } else {
                odd[oddCount++] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Even array : ");

        for(int i = 0; i<even.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(even[i] + " ");
        }
        
        System.out.println("Odd array : ");
        for(int i = 0; i<even.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print(odd[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

I expected this:
Original array : 23 4 5 78 34 56 12 20 33 2 76 11 29 9 54
Even array: 2 4 12 20 34 54 56 76 78
Odd array: 5 9 11 23 29 33

But im getting null values while printing the even and odd arrays

Output:
Enter 15 numbers
23
46
74
523
673
254
34
12
345
5755
344
33
5675
23242
3454
Even array :
12 34 46 74 254 344 3454 23242 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Odd array :
23 33 345 523 673 5675 5755 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

Comment: An uninitialized int array’s elements are all zero when it is created.  Use evenCount and oddCount in your last two printing loops.  That is, `i<evenCount` and `i<oddCount`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Your `even` and `odd` arrays have the same length as the original array (`15`), so if you print the full arrays, you'll see `0` values in the high indices of the arrays.

You should only print the `even` and `odd` array elements to which you assigned values. You can use your `evenCount` and `oddCount` counters for this purpose.

Change

```
    for(int i = 0; i<even.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(even[i] + " ");
    }
    
    System.out.println("Odd array : ");
    for(int i = 0; i<even.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(odd[i] + " ");
    }
```

to

```
    for(int i = 0; i<evenCount; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(even[i] + " ");
    }
    
    System.out.println("Odd array : ");
    for(int i = 0; i<oddCount; i++)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(odd[i] + " ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a counter variable to count the even numbers in the original array, which is not used. Use it to calculate the right size of your new arrays.

```
int[] even = new int[counter];
int[] odd = new int[15 - counter];
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I have been trying to to create the even and odd arrays but its giving null values while printing ..."*

This is because *even* and *odd* were initialized to 15 elements.

A source array of 15 elements won't produce 15 elements for both outputs arrays.
Thus, at least one array will contain remaining, uninitialized values.

```java
int[] even = new int[15];
int[] odd = new int[15];
```

You can trim the *arrays* with the *[Arrays#copyOfRange](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int%5B%5D,int,int))* method.

```java
even = Arrays.copyOfRange(even, 0, evenCount);
odd = Arrays.copyOfRange(odd, 0, oddCount);
```

Or, use a *[List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)* object, which has a non-fixed size.

```java
List<Integer> even = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<>();
for (int n : arr) (n % 2 == 0 ? even : odd).add(n);
```

Additionally, another approach would be to count the even and odd values first, and then create the arrays in a subsequent iteration.

```java
int evenCount = 0, oddCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) evenCount++;
    else oddCount++;
}

int[] even = new int[evenCount];
int[] odd = new int[oddCount];
evenCount = oddCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
        even[evenCount++] = arr[i];
    } else {
        odd[oddCount++] = arr[i];
    }
}
```

Also, you can print the *arrays* with *[Arrays#toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D))*, if you want to avoid the *for-loop*.

```java
System.out.println("Even array : " + Arrays.toString(even));
System.out.println("Odd array : " + Arrays.toString(odd));
```

On a final note, you have a typo in your code.
The *odd* array *loop* is conditional to *i<even.length*.

```java
System.out.println("Odd array : ");
for(int i = 0; i<even.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print(odd[i] + " ");
}
```

Output

```
Enter 15 numbers
23 4 5 78 34 56 12 20 33 2 76 11 29 9 54
Even array : [2, 4, 12, 20, 34, 54, 56, 76, 78]
Odd array : [5, 9, 11, 23, 29, 33]
```

```
Enter 15 numbers
23 46 74 523 673 254 34 12 345 5755 344 33 5675 23242 3454
Even array : [12, 34, 46, 74, 254, 344, 3454, 23242]
Odd array : [23, 33, 345, 523, 673, 5675, 5755]
```

Here is how I would implement the same code.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
List<Integer> list, even, odd;
even = new ArrayList<>();
odd = new ArrayList<>();
list = new ArrayList<>();
for (String string : scanner.nextLine().split(" +"))
    list.add(Integer.parseInt(string));
for (int a = 0, b; a < list.size() - 1; a++)
    for (b = 0; b < list.size() - a - 1; b++)
        if (list.get(b) > list.get(b + 1))
            Collections.swap(list, b, b + 1);
list.forEach(x -> (x % 2 == 0 ? even : odd).add(x));
System.out.printf("%s%n%s%n", even, odd);
```

Output

```
23 4 5 78 34 56 12 20 33 2 76 11 29 9 54
[2, 4, 12, 20, 34, 54, 56, 76, 78]
[5, 9, 11, 23, 29, 33]
```